# How to trim keys and values of an object?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

How can I achieve this?

Input:

```
{ CA: 20, "CA ":10, MA:" 10"}
```

Output:

```
{ CA: 20, "CA": 10, MA:"10" }
```

or

```
{ CA: 20, CA: 10, MA: 10}
```

Comment: `{ CA: 20, CA: 10}` An object doesn't contains a duplicate key

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I am doing some filtering and mapping of data from a big json file. I want to trim this result and add up the numbers using _.groupBy() and _.mapObject()

Comment: if there aren't supposed to be any spaces anywhere, a string replace() on the JSON before parse()ing would be the simplest, maybe even the fastest solution too.

Comment: @dandavis that sounds like a solution.. I'll give it a shot! Thanks!